# Rails app on big machine only gets 60 requests/sec benchmark results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ubuntu-11.04, apachebench

I'm hosting a Rails app on a beefy machine that -- I think -- should be able to handle a much higher load than I'm giving it. Here are the underwhelming test results from ApacheBench:

```
ab -kc 250 -n 1000 -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" https://www.mysite.com/

Server Software:        nginx/1.0.15
Server Hostname:        www.mysite.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1/SSLv3,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        4258 bytes

Concurrency Level:      250
Time taken for tests:   16.498 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
HTML transferred:       4258000 bytes
Requests per second:    60.61 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4124.432 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       16.498 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          282.83 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      302 1801 866.3   1623    3583
Processing:   183 1993 867.9   1873    7050
Waiting:      183 1880 864.2   1743    7036
Total:       1397 3794 1389.0   3558   10580

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   3558
  66%   4012
  75%   4179
  80%   4712
  90%   4947
  95%   6411
  98%   8376
  99%   8380
 100%  10580 (longest request)
```

Yuck. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I feel like I should be able to get much higher than 60 requests per second, and a much lower time-per-request than 4.1 seconds.

The app is sitting on a c1.xlarge EC2 instance (7 GB of memory 20 EC2 Compute Units, 8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each, 1690 GB of instance storage 64-bit platform, I/O Performance: High). The site root that the ApacheBench benchmark ran against is being action-cached, and doesn't even touch the database. A single request to it looks like this:

```
Started GET "/" for ##.###.###.## at Thu Apr 19 13:05:50 +0000 2012
  Processing by OneOfMyControllers#index as HTML
  Read fragment views/www.mysite.com/index (1.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 2ms
```

The machine is running Ubuntu 11.04, and I'm using Rails 3.1, Ruby Enterprise Edition, Passenger, and nginx. My nginx config looks like this:

```
worker_processes  8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8;

    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_app_spawner_idle_time 0;
    rails_framework_spawner_idle_time 0;

    passenger_max_pool_size 60;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 1000;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:3m;  # 3MB can hold about 12k SSL cache sessions
    ssl_session_timeout 5m; # average user spends 5 minutes on our site

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on; # useful with the sendfile option
    tcp_nodelay    off; 

    keepalive_timeout     10;
    send_timeout          10;
    client_body_timeout   10;
    client_header_timeout 10;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_static       on;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_comp_level   4;
    gzip_buffers      16 4k;
    gzip_min_length   1000;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_vary         on;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_http_version 1.0; # Amazon CloudFront uses HTTP/1.0                                            

    include /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And inside of /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/mysite.com, I've got:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    mysite.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen         443;
    ssl            on;
    server_name    mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate           /opt/mysite/ssl/wildcard_gandi_2012/combined-certification.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /opt/mysite/ssl/wildcard_gandi_2012/monserveur.key;
    ssl_protocols             SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen            80;
    server_name       *.mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    root /opt/mysite/public;

    passenger_enabled on;

    access_log  /opt/mysite/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log   /opt/mysite/log/nginx_error.log;

    # Set the maximum file upload size to 25 MB.
    client_max_body_size 25M;
}
server {
    listen            443;
    ssl               on;
    server_name       *.mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate           /opt/mysite/ssl/wildcard_gandi_2012/combined-certification.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /opt/mysite/ssl/wildcard_gandi_2012/monserveur.key;
    ssl_protocols             SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    root /opt/mysite/public;

    passenger_enabled on;

    access_log  /opt/mysite/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log   /opt/mysite/log/nginx_error.log;

    # Set the maximum file upload size to 25 MB.
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    # Asset caching
    location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
        root /opt/mysite/public;
        gzip_static on;
        access_log off;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Last-Modified "";
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }
}
```

Any idea why I can't get anymore than 60 requests/sec? Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: did you repeated the benchmarks more times? it could be a network problem...

Comment: Yep, I've even tried running it from the same machine as the Rails app.

Comment: Hmmm, just found this: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/06/09/does-rails-performance-need-an-overhaul/ Maybe 60 request/second is standard? Although I feel like I've seen a lot of people whose Rails apps get much higher. Is Passenger the problem?

Comment: Did you consider using unicorn?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll look into it. Is there a reason that it would scale much better than Passenger on REE?

Comment: Hook it up to New Relic and determine whether it is your database queries, ruby time (rendering templates, garbage collection), or something else. You can probably add some fragment caches on query results or generated templates, and significantly improve throughput on the same hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of your big issues is https.

I've just run some comparison benchmarks and for me they are showing a 2-4 times speed decrease on a really basic page like that. Do your metrics increase if you hit an HTTP page?

Also check your passenger status (`rvmsudo passenger-status`) to check that all the processes are loaded and getting requests distributed among them evenly.